# How can I prepend the value of a variable to a column in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, variable, printf

I have a script that outputs a column of text. I want to prepend each entry in the column with a string stored as a variable. How can I do this?

For example, consider the command

```
$ echo -e "john\npaul\ngeorge\nringo"
john
paul
george
ringo
```

Now, I'd like to prepend each entry in this column with the value of the environment variable `$HOME`. I've tried piping into `awk` like this:

```
$ echo -e "john\npaul\ngeorge\nringo" | awk '{printf("%s%s\n", $HOME, $1)}'
johnjohn
paulpaul
georgegeorge
ringoringo
```

This output is not what I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: of *those users'* home directory, or the (single) value of the current user's $HOME?

Comment: @JeffSchaller of the current user's `$HOME`. Didn't mean to imply that I was echoing actual users, just wanted to choose some somewhat arbitrary text.